# how to find matching patterns in strings irrespective of order?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, nlp

I am trying to match patterns between two strings. For example, I have

```
pattern_search = ['education four year'] 
string1 = 'It is mandatory to have at least of four years of professional education'
string2 = 'need to have education four years with professional degree'
```

I am trying a way to say true when i try to find match between pattern_search and string1 & string2.

When I am using regex library match/search/findall doesn't help me. In string i have the all the words required but not in order, in string2 i have one extra word with added plural.

Currently I am splitting the strings checking with each word in pattern_search with each word in string1 & 2 after preprocessing, is there any way to find match between the sentences?

Comment: Just curious, are you trying to create your own plagarism checking service?

Comment: hahahaha, so funnny and nice. But I am trying to classify type for a given string based on the keywords matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a nice look at the [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/difflib.html) library, specifically the [`get_close_matches`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches) function which returns words that are "close enough" to fill that requirement of words that may not exactly match. Be sure to adjust your threshold (`cutoff=`) accordingly.

```
from difflib import get_close_matches
from re import sub

pattern_search = 'education four year'
string1 = 'It is mandatory to have at least of four years of professional education'
string2 = 'need to have education four years with professional degree'
string3 = 'We have four years of military experience'

def match(string, pattern):
  pattern = pattern.lower().split()
  words = set(sub(r"[^a-z0-9 ]", "", string.lower()).split())  # Sanitize input
  return all(get_close_matches(word, words, cutoff=0.8) for word in pattern)

print(match(string1, pattern_search))  # True
print(match(string2, pattern_search))  # True
print(match(string3, pattern_search))  # False
```

If you want to make `pattern_search` a list of patterns, then you should probably loop through the `match` function.

Comment: This answer is based on the assumption that you're trying to compare `pattern_search` against `string1` and another scenario comparing `pattern_search` against `string2`, NOT `string1` vs. `string2` with a helper `pattern_search`.

Comment: difflib all example are considering letters(alphabets) alone but not words.

Comment: @Raady, My solution is based on words and similar words, not letters. You can add `print({word: get_close_matches(word, words, cutoff=0.8) for word in pattern})` before the `return` in my solution to get diagnostic information on matching words. See my [repl](https://repl.it/repls/MisguidedImmediateOpengl) for example playground.

Answer (score -1):

Try it:

```
def have_same_words(string1, string2):
    return sorted(string1.split()) == sorted(string2.split())

print(have_same_words("It is mandatory to have at least of four years of professional education", "education four year"))
```

Comment: match/search/find didnt help because if the words are in exact order they will be true. in string1 i have all the words but order in not same.

Comment: please read the topic, i said i am doing the same by splitting and comparision. i am not able to apply that because my whole data is huge. your method make it feel program is stuck somewhere on huge data.

Answer (score -2):

In Python to check if a string contains another string you can try a couple of things:

Use in

```
>>> pattern_search in string
True
```

Or find

```
>>> string1.find(pattern_search)
[returns value greater than 1 if True or -1 if False]
```

Comment: you have answered the same in new way !